# Jade loop optimization

Tags: loops, optimization, pug

I currently have an each loop in a Jade template which loops through a data set adding each entry as a row in table, with an if statement determining which class to apply to the tr. Everything works as expected however it's a little slow (adds about 50ms to load time with 100 entries in data set) Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

```
table
  thead
    tr
      th Type
      th Quantity
      th Price
      th Total
      th Time Stamp
  tbody
    each trade in trade_history
      if trade.type == '0'
        tr.success
          td BUY
          td
            =trade.amount
          td
            =trade.price
          td
            =trade.total
          td
            =trade.time
      else
        tr.danger 
          td SELL
          td
            =trade.amount
          td
            =trade.price
          td
            =trade.total
          td
            =trade.time
```

Comment: I have ended up optimizing other areas of the code to get the load times down (by 100ms with 100 entries in data set). However still interested in whether there is a more efficient way to do the loop in regards to both execution time and code. Having the tr alone inside the if statement and the td's outside (to avoid duplication) would be ideal. However jade either doesn't like it, or i'm indenting wrong.